# Read the byte format of txt file in c#

Tags: c#, byte

Let's say I have a C# console app, and I want to print the byte format of a text file as a string. I tried:

```
string bytesFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"My file here");
System.Console.Writeline(bytesFromFile);
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

But it VS just gives me and error and says: Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'string'. So then I tried this:

```
Array bytesFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"My file here");
System.Console.Writeline(bytesFromFile);
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

This time, it didn't give me any errors, but when I ran it, the console line printed: System.Byte[]

Why is this? Could someone please help me?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  What are the contents of the file, and what do you expect to print out?

Comment: Change in First code ReadAllBytes to ReadAllText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UTF8 encoding to convert the bytes to a string.

```
var bytesFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"My file here");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFromFile));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: And how do you know that OP's file uses UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
var bytesFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"My file here");
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFromFile);
System.Console.Writeline(result);
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

If you are not using/sure about UTF-8 then use Default like the following : `Encoding.Default.GetString(bytesFromFile);`

Comment: And how do you know that OP's file uses UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: if not sure then use `Encoding.Default.GetString(array)`

Comment: That may also fail, if the encoding is UTF-16 for instance.  That's the problem with guessing.